# How can find the Favorite button and click it with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Updated description:

Here is the listing from Redfin.com https://www.redfin.com/CA/Sunnyvale/735-Grape-Ave-94087/home/1835008, what I want to locate and click is the "Favorite" button on the top-right corner. I've tried the code in the old description as well as all the suggestions by others, but none of them works.

Can someone guide me how to locate the icon in Selenium webdriver?

Thanks a lot!

+++++++++++++++++BELOW IS OLD PROBLEM DESCRIPTION+++++++++++++++++++++++++
I have this button:

```
<div role="button" title="Favorite" tabindex="0" class="clickable button tertiary-alt" data-rf-test-name="homeControlButton">
<span><svg class="SvgIcon rfSvg favorite svg-icon-off-color" style="height:24px;width:24px"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"></svg></svg></span>
</div>
```

But I tried with find XPath by:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='clickable button tertiary-alt' and @title='favorite']").click()
```

But it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: The button title is `Favorite` not `favorite`

Comment: What Danielle said... and you probably can make that locator simpler. I'm assuming that using the `title` is enough to uniquely locate the element on the page, e.g. `//div[@title='Favorite']"`.

Comment: @DanielleM. Hi Daniel, I've updated the problem description, can you please let me know if you have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR , "div[data-rf-test-name='abp-favoriteButton'] div[role='button']")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-rf-test-name='abp-favoriteButton'] div[role='button']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks you. But the Favorite isn't wrapped inside a iframe, it's in div. I've updated the problem description, can you please let me know if you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer with the tested code. It's working for me. Let me know if you still have issue.

Comment: I've tried again, but still it cannot find it :(
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: div[data-rf-test-name='abp-favoriteButton'] div[role='button']`

Comment: Thank you Supputuri. I found the root cause. I have to wait until the page is fully loaded. After I explicitly wait for few seconds, the problem solved!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".clickable.button.tertiary-alt");
```

Or you could do

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[title=\"Favorite\"]");
```

Comment: I've updated the problem description, can you please let me know if you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `$('[title="Favorite"]')` I ran that in the console and it found it. This div is not nested in any frames, so the same selector will work with selenium. `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[title='Favorite']");` If that doesn't work, there is definitely something wrong with your selenium driver, and you may want to update it, or downgrade it.

Comment: thanks, but I still cannot find the Favorite, please see the following log.
`browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[title='Favorite']").click()
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [title='Favorite']`

Comment: Thanks Asyranok! I found the root cause. The reason why Favorite cannot be found is because the page isn't fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following XPath:

```
//div[@title='Favorite']
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@title='Favorite']
It looks like it still cannot be able to find the button :(

Comment: @damingzi, seems your element inside the `iframe`. So, first, switch to it before interaction with the element.

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element you can target the child `<span>` tag and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.clickable.button.tertiary-alt[title='Favorite']>span").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='clickable button tertiary-alt' and @title='Favorite']/span").click()
  ```

Comment: Check if there are any  frames or window. `print(len(driver.window_handles))` and `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')))`.

Comment: @supputuri (len(driver.window_handles)) == 1 and len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')) == 6, does it say anything? Thanks!

Comment: @damingzi Yes, it does. Your element is inside `iframe`. In order to find the element you have to switch the context to look for elements inside the `iframe`

Comment: Ah, that's great. So here is a learning opportunity for both of us. Make sure you add as much of your code as possible. If I had seen the lines of code before this driver.find logic, I would have instantly seen that you weren't waiting for the page to fully load before searching for this element. And I will also make sure that I request that extra info next time as well.

Comment: 4 contributors and 7 days of intercommunication to solve a question counts as a bit expensive but glad to know OP got a working solution. The key takeaways would be 1)To provide as much as possible _back ground context_ 2) _Expected output_ 3) Relevant _HTML_ or _link_ to the site 4) _Code trials_ and 5) _Error stack trace_. In presence of these 5 parameters nailing the bug/defect/issue becomes much easier.